# Configure build.gradle for building apps with different application id

Tags: android, android-manifest, build.gradle, android-productflavors

I need to generate different apks from the same code. The only difference would be the applicationId defined in build.gradle. I have defined some permissions in AndroidManifest. These permissions start with the application id. e.g.

**APK1**
build.gradle applicationId 'com.example.app1'

Android Manifest

uses-permission android:name="com.example.app1.permission.PERMISSION_NAME"

**APK2**
build.gradle applicationId 'com.example.app2'

Android Manifest

uses-permission android:name="com.example.app2.permission.PERMISSION_NAME"

I need to know an efficient way to achieve this. If possible, I would like to avoid creating two different AndroidManifest files depending on the flavour. Please suggest.

Comment: internet search "android gradle manifest" results - first link: "Inject Build Variables into the Manifest"

Comment: Thanks it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `${applicationId}` placeholder.
Something like:

```
<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.PERMISSION_NAME" />
```